# PHP MySQL invoice materials

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some troubles getting this code to work properly. Our employees has access to our backend system on our website. This is how the input fields and such are set up:

```
<?
$materialer_query = $db->query("SELECT faktura_materialer.id as materialer_id, faktura.*, faktura_materialer.* FROM faktura, faktura_materialer WHERE faktura_materialer.faktura_id = faktura.id");

while($mat = $materialer_query->fetch_object()){
    ?>                      
    <tr>
        <td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="beskrivelse_nu" value="<? print $mat->beskrivelse; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="enhed_nu" value="<? print $mat->enhed; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="stk_nu" value="<? print $mat->stk; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="vejl_eks_moms_nu" value="<? print number_format($mat->vejl_eks_moms,2,",","."); ?>"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a></td>

        <input hidden name="materiale_id" value="<? print $mat->materialer_id; ?>">
    </tr>                       
    <?
}
?>
```

I want to be able to update every material in one page. I've tried to mess around with this, even added a hidden input field in the while loop, which contains every material id. And this is how I currently update the table:

```
$beskrivelse_nu         = addslashes($_POST['beskrivelse_nu']);
$enhed_nu               = addslashes($_POST['enhed_nu']);
$stk_nu                 = addslashes($_POST['stk_nu']);
$vejl_eks_moms_nu       = addslashes($_POST['vejl_eks_moms_nu']);

$db->query("UPDATE faktura_materialer
    SET beskrivelse         = '".$beskrivelse_nu."',
    enhed                   = '".$enhed_nu."',
    stk                     = '".$stk_nu."',
    vejl_eks_moms           = '".$vejl_eks_moms_nu."'

    WHERE id                = '".$_POST['materiale_id']."' AND
    faktura_id              = '".$_faktura->faktura_id."'
");
```

Everytime I change something in the input fields it just change every row to the same..
I'll hope you all understand what I want :)

Comment: All input fields and table names are in Danish - sorry.

Comment: Are you trying to update every record in the table?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the records for the specified invoice. But it just change all the rows in the table to the same..

Comment: Where is `$_faktura` coming from? @user3294602

Comment: Its a fetch object which is fetching data from my faktura table

Comment: I don't see any reference to it anywhere else but in `'".$_faktura->faktura_id."'` @user3294602

Comment: Its not in the code i provided but that part works just fine. :)

Comment: I suggest printing out the query separately and then try to execute that query manually in phpmyadmin

Comment: But how will that help me within our backend system?

Comment: It helps me a lot. I often print the queries so you can see what each query being ran is. Very helpful for debugging stuff like this

Comment: When im printing out my post variable then i only get the last material..

Comment: I would assign every query that you run into a variable first, echo that variable right before the $db->query call. That way you can see each query being ran. From what you have provided us there is no reason (that I can see at least) as to why multiple rows are getting overwritten. Problem may be in removerow(this) function

Comment: But shouldnt my query update the rows just fine? The WHERE statement are specifieing the id of each column

Comment: Yes the query looks fine from what I can see. Are you calling that query using Ajax?

Comment: No - just php. Im using javascript to add more fields to the form

Comment: The only reason I can think of as to why this is happening is that all the id's must be the same...

Comment: Hmm, the id's are not the same.. ill try again tomorrow. Thanks any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you generate the fields through the loop you end up with multiple set of fields with the same field names.
In other words, if your `$materialer_query` returns 4 rows, then your html will have 4 times `<input hidden name="materiale_id" value="<? print $mat->materialer_id; ?>">`...

If you really need to have all the fields on the same page, then you can do it in two ways:

First option. You can create separate form per row. and submit them separately.

```
while($mat = $materialer_query->fetch_object()){
?>
<form action="--somewhere-to-process--" method="post">
<table><tr>
    <td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="beskrivelse_nu" value="<? print $mat->beskrivelse; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="enhed_nu" value="<? print $mat->enhed; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="stk_nu" value="<? print $mat->stk; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="vejl_eks_moms_nu" value="<? print number_format($mat->vejl_eks_moms,2,",","."); ?>"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a>
 <input type="submit" value="Update">
 </td>

    <input hidden name="materiale_id" value="<? print $mat->materialer_id; ?>">
</tr></table>
</form>                       
<?
}
```

Second option is you create one form, but each field name is uniquer throughout the form.
Something like this:

```
while($mat = $materialer_query->fetch_object()){
?>
<tr>
    <td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="faktura[<?=$mat->faktura_id?>][beskrivelse_nu]" value="<? print $mat->beskrivelse; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="faktura[<?=$mat->faktura_id?>][enhed_nu]" value="<? print $mat->enhed; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="faktura[<?=$mat->faktura_id?>][stk_nu]" value="<? print $mat->stk; ?>"></td>
    <td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="faktura[<?=$mat->faktura_id?>][vejl_eks_moms_nu]" value="<? print number_format($mat->vejl_eks_moms,2,",","."); ?>"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a>
 <input type="submit" value="Update">
 </td>

    <input hidden name="faktura[<?=$mat->faktura_id?>][materiale_id" value="<? print $mat->materialer_id; ?>">
</tr>
<?
}
```

This way your `$_POST[faktura]` will be an associative array with faktura-id keys and their updated value.
Scroll through the array and update the DB from each array.

Please keep in mind that qty of fields in a form is limited. So make sure not to have hundreds fields in the form :)

Comment: But how should the query be like if I go with the second option?  :)

Comment: Initial query will not change. It already has all the data for all rows. Just make sure that everything passed with the post.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the query be passing the array instead of just a single POST?

Comment: Misunderstanding....
DB query will read all faktura records and output them on the page filling the fields.
After you click 'update' it will POST everything to another page having all your records as part of the POST. Namely: `$_POST["faktura"]` will have all your records with updates stored as associative array, where keys are faktura IDs.
Your PHP page have to scroll through `$_POST["faktura"]` and update oll DB records one-by-one.